# Clarifications and Concrete examples of Software Architecture Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I am studying Software Architecture Patterns and I am struggling to relate these patterns to modern development stacks and frameworks in a concrete way. It feels like there is a disconnect between learning design patterns / architecture patterns and then writing actual code.

For example, if you take the example of a react application, using redux for state management, with a Node / Express API, which uses mongoose as an ORM to access a MongoDB (so basically the MERN stack), which architecture is this? I could see making an argument for a layered / n-tier pattern, a service oriented pattern (or microservice if having multiple smaller APIs), possibly component-based structural pattern in the react client (or even MVC). Is this a hybrid, a Frankenstein or are patterns just out?

So my question is: Can someone explain, or point me towards, a concrete explanation of how these patterns apply to modern development stacks and frameworks?

I would greatly appreciate some clarification here.

Comment: This question sounds more appropriate for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question seems too wide. Try to scope it so that you ask about specific framework.

Comment: Actually, I did exactly that. I gave a specific example of a technology stack and requested feedback for a single example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have decided the architecture strategy that will achieve your business requirements (that's a full complex topic by itself). Your next step is to select the stack that meets your skills and architecture (patterns) requirements: [micro-services](https://microservices.io/patterns/index.html), [Serverless](https://www.jeremydaly.com/serverless-microservice-patterns-for-aws), etc.

Your confusion comes from the fact most stacks fit with a few different architecture patterns. From this list of [usual (pattern) suspects](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-common-software-architectural-patterns-in-a-nutshell-a0b47a1e9013), your MERN example can implement well the Layered and Model-View-Controller patterns but implement poorly (if possible) the Event-Bus pattern.

As for everything in software architecture and development, the key is ***experience***. How to gather experience regarding the architecture patterns?

My recommendation would be to start with ***opinionated*** stacks that are considered as a reference implementation of the patterns you have chosen. By doing so, you will get quickly familiar on the job with the patterns.

Example 1: Elm supports ***only*** the [Model View Update](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/). What could be seen as a lack of flexibility is actually a strength, because it does only one thing but it does it very well! The Elm architecture has became a major inspiration for many other Web stacks and famously React + Redux.

Example 2: Frameworks like [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) are more versatile but they glue in a consistent manner many internal or third-party components. You can also learn a lot because these frameworks support the architecture patterns better than if you did them yourself the first time.

Once you start to feel you're reaching the limitations of the framework to achieve your goals : Congratulations! It means you've become quite familiar with the patterns and that you might consider implement them in your own way (Ex.: I don't like [CQRS à la NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs)). Or that you need to enrich your pattern catalog to address the new use cases you're tasked with.

Code, rinse, repeat.